# Manga in which the main character gets trapped in a dungeon and almost dies, but is saved by a girl that happens to be a magical tree of life

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

The main character (MC) gets trapped in a dungeon and almost dies, but is saved by a girl that happens to be a magical tree of life.  If I remember correctly, the girl/tree had a witch (or some other sort of magical woman) as her guardian, and the witch decides to train the MC. They also give him a magical tree branch and a magical eye which allows the MC to communicate with them.

I remember reading it in Mangadex, like 3 years ago I think; it was translated into English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is ***[The Unfavorable Job [Appraiser] Is Actually the Strongest](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=171567)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> When a child is born, they are granted a "Job" by the goddess of light. Unfortunately, Ain is granted the unfavourable job of an [Appraiser]. All he can do is appraise materials, and so he is treated horribly by his own party. Then, one day, he happens to come across an S-Ranked tree hidden in a dungeon. Following this encounter, Ain slowly but surely changes...

The protagonist, Ain, is a member of a party of adventurers, but is looked down upon by his comrades due to his job of 'Appraiser', which is viewed as a weak skill.

While exploring a dungeon, the party is confronted by a large group of Hellhounds, and Ain's comrades decide to paralyse him with a spell and leave him for the hounds, to cover their escape. The hounds tear into Ain, but the paralysis spell wears off quickly enough for him to briefly fight them off and run after his party. However, he discovers that they've blocked the entrance to the dungeon, so he's forced to flee into another room, where he finds himself at the edge of a huge chasm. With nowhere left to run, he decides he'd rather plunge to his death than be eaten alive, so he steps off the edge and falls.

He then wakes up, broken and bloodied, by the roots of an enormous tree, where he's approached by a mysterious girl who kisses him on the forehead and then disappears. Ain isn't quite sure what just happened, but discovers that all his wounds have been magically healed. Using his appraisal skill, he also realises that the tree in front of him is a Yggdrasil, a rare, sacred tree which provides unlimited mana.

Seeking to leave the dungeon, Ain exits the room with the tree. However, he's soon attacked by a flying gremlin, which starts hacking pieces off of him with a sythe. And as if that wasn't bad enough, a Death Bear shows up and rakes his face with its claws, destroying his left eye. The bear's about to bite Ain's head off, when a small witch appears and beheads it with a spell, saving him.

Ain wakes up again, back in the room with the tree, his wounds magically healed once more. The witch, Ursula, then explains that she's the guardian of the Yggdrasil tree, and that the girl who kissed him before, Yuri, is the spirit of the tree, and her 'daughter'. She also explains that Yuri replaced his damaged eye with a 'Spirit's Artificial Eye'.

At Yuri's request, Ursula reluctantly agrees to train Ain, so that he's powerful enough to leave the dungeon on his own, without being killed by the monsters between him and the exit. Ursula also gives him a wooden sword, made from one of Yuri's branches, as a weapon to use against the monsters.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is it! Thank you